# JPA- Cannot clear a column value

Tags: jpa

I was debugging a converter functionality for two of my columns and by chance hard-coded a value in setExpDtCym(String expDtCym). Even though i deleted this change, subsequent queries keep fetching the hard-coded value! I decompiled the class and made sure the change is reflected, cleared jboss cache, played around clear(), evict() methods of entity manager - with no luck.

But, when i try to hardcode with a different static value the new value is picked up! In short, jpa refuses to use the value from the database. I have never come across this issue and not able to find whats going on. Please help.. Thanks!

```
@Basic
@Column(name = "EFF_DT_CYM", nullable = false, length = 6)
@Convert(converter = StringToYearDateConverter.class)
public String getEffDtCym() {
    return effDtCym;
}

public void setEffDtCym(String effDtCym) {
    this.effDtCym = effDtCym;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "EXP_DT_CYM", nullable = false, length = 6)
@Convert(converter = StringToYearDateConverter.class)
public String getExpDtCym() {
    return expDtCym;
}

public void setExpDtCym(String expDtCym) {
    //this.expDtCym = "test";
    this.expDtCym = expDtCym;
}
```

Comment: cleared the object out of both L1 and L2 caches? Any JPA provider has a log that should tell you what communication happens with DB ... best look at it

Comment: Thanks Billy. Below is from the JPA log.. How is it finding my hard-coded text is a mystery

[TRACE] 19 Nov 2018 16:03:14,895 ->org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor:74:: Found [test  ] as column [EXP_DT_12_3_]